# How can I configure a grid view column to hold a hyperlink myself?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm filling in a DataTable with all the necessary data. I want the "Process" column to hold a hyperlink so that it directs to a specific page when clicked (based on the Process name.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Object[] row = new Object[7];
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.Text = Process.ToString();
link.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/IndexSummary?Process={0}", Process.ToString());
row[0] = link;

//...Fill in rest of row

dt.LoadDataRow(row,false);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I execute this code, "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink" shows up for every row. This is my GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="3"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        AllowSorting="True" SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc-header" 
        SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc-header" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="17" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PagerStyle-Font-Names="WebDings" PagerStyle-Font-Size="Medium"
        PagerSettings-FirstPageText=" 7 " PagerSettings-PreviousPageText=" 3 " 
        PagerSettings-NextPageText=" 4 " PagerSettings-LastPageText=" 8 " 
          Font-Size="Small" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
          onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

<PagerSettings FirstPageText=" 7 " LastPageText=" 8 " Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"     NextPageText=" 4 " PreviousPageText=" 3 "></PagerSettings>

        <PagerStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DCE2E8" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc-header"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc-header"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
     </asp:GridView>
```

How can I change this to show the hyperlink correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just coming back to answer my question in case it can help someone else out:

I had to do the hyperlink adding in the RowDataBound event like this:

```
       protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {
        String Process = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.Text = Process;
        link.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/IndexSummary.aspx?Process={0}&Machine={1}&Date={2}", Process, Request.QueryString["Machine"], Request.QueryString["Date"]);
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);

       }
```